# Meteor Event Selectors for more complex events

Tags: javascript, meteor, dom-events, meteor-blaze

I am trying to get a event handler in meteorjs to work as expected:

- The White box should be clickable, if it is clicked, I need to call a function that closes or opens a chapter
- when clicking the greyish text (which is a `contenteditable <div>`) you should be able to edit that `contenteditable` and has a class `.editable`

[image: Screenshot of my application]

My Problem: I have declared an event handler like this:

```
Template.chapterBox.events:
   'click .chapter-box': (e) ->
      do_some_stuff()
```

how would it be possible to prevent that above event handler from firing when I click the contenteditable to edit it?

I already about something like this in the first line of the event handler

```
if $(e.target).hasClass("editable"):
  return;
```

but it did not work

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
<template name="ChapterBox">
  <div class="chapter-box">
    <div class='editable'>Text</div>
  </div>
</template>

Template.ChapterBox.events({
  'click .chapter-box': function (event, template) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("clicked chapter-box: ", event.currentTarget);  
  },

 'click .editable': function(event,template){
    event.stopPropagation();
   console.log("clicked editable: ", event.currentTarget);  
  }
});
```

Check this [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/WeQgbtDBizLM54689/Meteor%20Event%20Selectors%20for%20more%20complex%20events) for a working example.

[Event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Comment: Thanks for your sulution. This made me think... in the end jQuery Draggable and Sortable broke the functionality of the contenteditable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this worked for me:

```
if (e.target.className == "editable") {
  console.log("clicked editable");
} else {
  console.log("clicked chapter-box");
}
```